# Is it a good to share common lib between wars? What are the things you should look for?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm, weblogic

For my project I have to deploy several spring boot applications on a weblogic server. Each application will be a standalone war and will include a common library containing several singleton beans (you know, configurations, services, etcetera).

For example:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConf{

     @Bean
     public DataSource create(@Value("${myshareddataurl}")String dataurl){
          return new MyDBDataSource();
     }
}
```

I'm tempted on sharing the common lib because, being each war on the application server, the underlying JVM should be the same. So, suppose I create 10 singleton in my lib and I have 20 wars that would lead to 20x10=200 singletons taking the memspace while, by sharing, I only have 10.

On the other hand, I'm afraid this could lead to some unexpected runtime bug. Take my previous code snippet: what would happen if the "myshareddataurl" is defined in the spring boot's application properties? Would the singleton bean be re-instanciated with the overridden property? Or a new singleton bean is to be created?
And what would happen if every property I use in my common lib was referred in an external property file (so the same for every spring boot)?

I'd like to hear your opinions about this matter, I don't want to  saturate my JVM memspace but I also need to know what is happening under the hood so to avoid bad configurations.

Comment: Shared libraries are good, wars are bad, Boot should handle your `DataSource` for you anyway.

Comment: But what is exactly happening?

Comment: WebLogic shared libs won't help you to reduce your instances number. Shared libs are helpful for development and deployment. During application deployment, each shared lib is merged with the application. Think as each shared lib is copied and merged with the application. So, you will still get 200 instances in your JVM.
Your common beans should be deployed in their own application and accessible through a protocol such as T3 (rmi) or http for instance.

Comment: But that would mean to not reuse anything..isn't there some other way to reduce memory footprint?